# Maven pom configuration to see the errors on netbeans console

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I have some problem when I try to run maven on netbeans the netbeans-console write:

Failed to execute goal XXXXXX on project MavenEnterpriseApp-ear: XXX failed (result=1) -> [Help 1]

My question is, existe some configuration on the pom that I can use to see what happend with the plugin without run mvn on console? and if not how can I do that?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke maven with the `-e` option to receive a more detailed error message including a stacktrace. This option can be set as the default in NetBeans by selecting

```
Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Maven
```

And adding `-e` to "Global Execution Options".